# I visited the US for 2 weeks in May; can I return in November for 2 more weeks?

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program

I went to visit a friend in the US for 2 weeks in May and was planning on flying over again in November for another 2 weeks. Is this allowed? I know you're only allowed to visit the US for 90 days before you have to leave. Does this mean I won't be allowed to return in November?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What exactly is your question?  You have stayed for 2 weeks and in November you want to stay for 3 months?  If that's the case what exactly are you confused about?

Comment: Because i've already entered the US in May for 2 weeks, The VWP only allowed entry for 90 days? If i have left after being in the country for 2 weeks will i be allowed entry again in november for just another 2 weeks?

Comment: @user18860 It allows 90 days per entry.  ESTA for VWP is valid for 2 years.

Answer (score 2):

If you did indeed leave after two weeks the first time, then there is no problem with visiting again in November. Since you mention "flying over", I'm assuming that you normally do not live in North America.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm new to all this stuff and it just has me confused. I wasn't sure if I'd be allowed back, I don't want to have any problems when i fly over and am sent back for overstaying or something.

Comment: Well, you can't have overstayed if you weren't there! :)

Comment: I live in the UK, I was visiting a friend for 2 weeks and was hoping to do it again in november for 2 weeks again is all.

Comment: Well thank you, I had myself worried i wouldn't be able to go back. All this stuff to me is rather complicated.

Comment: Fortunately, for UK citizens it's not nearly as complicated as it is for citizens of some other countries (India, China, Russia...).

Comment: I do plan in the future to visit longer then 2 weeks. I know for like a 6 month visit i need a visa of some kind? might you be able to tell me what sort of visa it is i would need to apply for? If not then that's okay of course. You just seem to understand this all much better then i do.

Comment: For longer than 90 days you would need to apply for a visa, yes. For information that applies to you, see the US Embassy page in London: http://london.usembassy.gov/niv/index.html. You would likely be looking for a B-2 visa, but I'm afraid I have no idea how long the maximum permitted stay is on a B-2 (or whether it is even possible for you to stay more than 90 days).

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for all your help! I'm very happy now, Was worried i wouldn't be able to go back, had such a great time! :) Thanks again, really appreciate it.